# Showing Login/register when user is not logged in

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, user-registration

I'm using the code below

```
<?php global $current_user; wp_get_current_user(); ?>
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
 echo 'سلام ' . $current_user->user_firstname . "\n"; echo '' . $current_user->user_lastname . "\n"; echo '/'; } 
else { wp_loginout(); } ?>
```

to show the first name and last name of user on top bar when they are logged in and I want to show the login/register when they're not logged in. it is working fine when they are logged in but it doesn't show the login/register when they are not logged in. is there sth wrong with my code? should i change anything? I will appreciate any kind of help. thx.

Comment: could you also show us what `wp_loginout();` does? That might be the issue.

Comment: according to wordpress code reffrence it should do this:
Description #
Displays a link, which allows users to navigate to the Log In page to log in or log out depending on whether they are currently logged in.
but it is not doing what it should. idk why :/

Comment: Your code is working for me, I placed in an empty page and it displayed this "Login"  hypertexted tot he wp-login.php page wp_loginout(); is correct and working.

Comment: Where are you placing this code anyway? what location or file, or the position in the page? is it in the frontend or the backend of wp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad to help!

Your code is right. As i've just checked, the only problem it can be, is in the `wp_loginout();` function.

I don't really know `wp_loginout();`'s real useage clearly, so i just guess it may output the **login/register** link you need.

I suggest you to replace `wp_loginout();` with my code below, and try again to see, if it works well.('login.php' is only an example)

```php
echo "<a href='login.php'>login/register</a>";
```

Hope it'll solve your problem,

Wish you a good day~

Comment: Thank you so much @MX-Qulin for your answer. I just checked the codes again. there was another line for the theme before my code
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() && SHOPKEEPER_WOOCOMMERCE_IS_ACTIVE ) {?>
 that was interfiering with my code i guess. I guess this was the problem. I swapped them and it is working now. also your code is correct. thanks in advance.